# Estimation of AR model with Durbin-Levinson

Tags: estimation, autocorrelation, stationarity, autoregressive

Let $X_t$ be a stationary time series. We have computed $\rho_1 = 0.8, \rho_2 = 0.5, \rho_3 = 0.4$. If we assume that an AR(3) model without a constant is appropriate, get estimates of $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$ and $\phi_3$ using Durbin-Levinson.

We have $$Y_t=\phi_1Y_{t-1} + \phi_2Y_{t-2}+ \phi_3 Y_{t-3} + \varepsilon_t$$
Durbin-Levinson gives us $$\phi_{kk}= \frac{\rho_k-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\phi_{k-1,j}\rho_{k-j}}{1-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\phi_{k-1,j}\rho_j} $$
This is the formula I was given, it is incomplete right ? I think we also need this formula I found on internet $$\phi_{n,k}=\phi_{n-1,k}-\phi_{n,n}\phi_{n-1,n-k} .$$

Once I found $\phi_{11},\phi_{21}...\phi_{33}$, what are the estimates of $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$ and $\phi_3$ ? The solution said it was $\phi_{31}, \phi_{32}$ and $\phi_{33}$ but without proof. I noticed that if we are trying to fit an $AR(p)$ model, then the estimates of $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_p$ are $\phi_{p1},\dots,\phi_{pp}$, but why is that ? I can't find any proof of this fact. Can someone provide one ?

Comment: When $(X_t)$ is not stationary, $\rho_k$ are meaningless because they potentially depend on $t.$